# data is not coming JSON parsing

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

```
let url1 = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url1)!)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
let urlSession = URLSession.shared
let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data,response,error) -> Void in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
        return
    }
    if let data = data {
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation({ () -> Void in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
})
task.resume()
```

With or without http method, response data is empty. What am I doing wrong? WiFi works fine. Maybe problem on my simulator settings?

```
  let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
            let posts = json as? [[String: Any]] ?? []

            print(posts)

            for post in posts{                    
                let product = Product()
                product.userId = post["userId"] as! Int
                product.id = post["id"] as! Int
                product.title = post["title"] as! String
                product.body = post["body"] as! String
                self.products.append(product)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }).resume()
```

Yeah thanks, but your code is not works too, i mean say data is empty, nothing to be parsed. WiFi on my emulator works fine maybe problem on my xcode8?

Comment: Please clarify what your issue is. What debugging have you done? What exactly happens when you run this code?

Comment: jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [[String:Any]] use this line

Comment: Check my answer just replace your method with mine one you got your output

Comment: thanks for everyone now its work

Answer (score 0):

**Made some changes in your code.**

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(NSURLRequest.init(URL: url!), completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
      guard let data = data where error == nil else { return }
       do {
          let posts = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments)
          print(posts)
          } catch let error as NSError {
                 print(error)
              }
          }).resume()
```

**Output :**
Here your all 100 post display